# PHP - sort array by parent and id (advanced)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of arrays - each has own id and parent id values.
I want to sort it so that every child should be beneath it's parent.
Let me show You my code:

1. Given Array:

   ```
   $arr = array(array('id' => 15, 'parent' => 12), 
   array('id' => 10, 'parent' => 12), 
   array('id' => 12, 'parent' => 12), 
   array('id' => 17, 'parent' => 12), 
   array('id' => 21, 'parent' => 15), 
   array('id' => 13, 'parent' => 15), 
   array('id' => 15, 'parent' => 15), 
   array('id' => 25, 'parent' => 15), 
   array('id' => 7, 'parent' => 7), 
   array('id' => 18, 'parent' => 7), 
   array('id' => 4, 'parent' => 7), 
   array('id' => 1, 'parent' => 3), 
   array('id' => 5, 'parent' => 5), 
   array('id' => 2, 'parent' => 7));
   ```
2. How the output should looki like (asc by parents, every children also ascending - always under parent (parent always as first)):

   ```
         0 =>
             'id' => int 1
             'parent' => int 3
         1 =>
             'id' => int 5
             'parent' => int 5
         2 =>
             'id' => int 7
             'parent' => int 7
         3 =>
             'id' => int 2
             'parent' => int 7
         4 =>
             'id' => int 4
             'parent' => int 7
         5 =>
             'id' => int 18
             'parent' => int 7
         6 =>
             'id' => int 12
             'parent' => int 12
         7 =>
             'id' => int 10
             'parent' => int 12
         8 =>
             'id' => int 15
             'parent' => int 12
         9 =>
             'id' => int 17
             'parent' => int 12
         10 =>
             'id' => int 15
             'parent' => int 15
         11 =>
             'id' => int 13
             'parent' => int 15
         12 =>
             'id' => int 21
             'parent' => int 15
         13 =>
             'id' => int 25
             'parent' => int 15
   ```
3. Question:
   I'am wondering what is the easiest solution to achieve this ? I've managed to do that, but I cant stop the feeling that there is a way to do that in quicker and more optimal way..
4. Here is my code:

   ```
   function groupByParent ($array)
   {
       $groups = array();
       foreach ($array as $a) {
           $groups[$a['parent']][] = $a;
       }
       return $groups;
   }
   function insideSort ($array)
   {
       foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
           usort($array[$k], function($a, $b){
              return $a['id'] == $b['parent'] ? -1 : 1;
           });
           $f = array_shift($array[$k]);
           sort($array[$k]);
           array_unshift($array[$k], $f);
       }
       return $array;
   }
   function finalSort($array)
   {
       $final = array();
       foreach ($array as $a) {
           $final = array_merge($final, $a);
       }
       return $final;
   }

   $grr = groupByParent($arr);
   $irr = insideSort($grr);
   ksort($irr);
   $res = finalSort($irr);
   ```
5. Is there easier way to achieve it ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) along with [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
array_multisort(
    array_column($arr, 'parent'),
    array_column($arr, 'id'),
    $arr
);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8e8aef06d26e8a3c9db3c1c0587abe43d1d8fa34).

I guess this is the simplest and the most right way to do, as [`array_multisort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php) was created for such cases.

Comment: not working - parents arent always on top of their children

Answer (score 0):

You want to look in to [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

```php
<?php
$arr = [
    ['id' => 15, 'parent' => 12],
    ['id' => 10, 'parent' => 12],
    ['id' => 12, 'parent' => 12],
    ['id' => 17, 'parent' => 12],
    ['id' => 21, 'parent' => 15],
    ['id' => 13, 'parent' => 15],
    ['id' => 15, 'parent' => 15],
    ['id' => 25, 'parent' => 15],
    ['id' => 7, 'parent' => 7],
    ['id' => 18, 'parent' => 7],
    ['id' => 4, 'parent' => 7],
    ['id' => 1, 'parent' => 3],
    ['id' => 5, 'parent' => 5],
    ['id' => 2, 'parent' => 7],
];
usort(
    $arr,
    function ($a, $b) {
        if ($a['parent'] == $b['parent']) {
            if ($a['id'] == $b['id']) {
                return 0;
            }

            return ($a['id'] < $b['id']) ? -1 : 1;
        }

        return ($a['parent'] < $b['parent']) ? -1 : 1;
    }
);
var_dump($arr);
```

This outputs

```
array(14) {
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [12]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [13]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(18)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(10)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(12)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(12)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(12)
  }
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(15)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(12)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(17)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(12)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(13)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(15)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(15)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(15)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(21)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(15)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(25)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(15)
  }
}
➜  promote-api git:(develop) ✗ php test.php
array(14) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(5)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(4)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(7)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(18)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(10)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(12)
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(12)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(12)
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(15)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(12)
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(17)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(12)
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(13)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(15)
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(15)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(15)
  }
  [12]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(21)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(15)
  }
  [13]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(25)
    ["parent"]=>
    int(15)
  }
}
```

Comment: as above - not working - parents arent always on top of their children